# Javascript animation only works in one direction

Tags: javascript

The webpage I'm trying to create has a bidirectional sliding animation on it. However the animation is only partially working. To be more precise, the animation slides up, but it only slides down partway. Here's my JavaScript:

```
function showLayer() {
var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.top);
if (layerPosition > 315) {
    hiddenLayer.style.top = (layerPosition - 5) + "px";
    setTimeout("showLayer()", 20);
}
}

function hideLayer() {
var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.top);
if (layerPosition <= 315) {
    hiddenLayer.style.top = (layerPosition + 5) + "px";
    setTimeout("hideLayer()", 20);
}
}
```

Notice on the fourth line of the hideLayer function, I have the condition set to <= 315, this is due to the fact that setting it equal to 315 causes the element to move only a few pixels in either direction after clicking the trigger element. Here's the HTML elements I have dedicated to the animation:

```
<div id="mainbutton" onclick="showLayer('mainmenu'); hideLayer('mainmenu')"></div>
<div id="mainmenu" style="position: absolute; top: 690px; left: 9px;"  
onclick="showLayer('mainmenu')">&nbsp;</div>
```

And here are the styles for them:

```
div#mainmenu { width: 600px; height: 350px; border-style: solid; background-color: 
rgb(0, 0, 0) ; border-width: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 7px; border-top-left-
radius: 7px; }
div#mainbutton { position: absolute; top: 674px; left: 12px; width: 28px; height: 
28px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 1px; border-
radius: 4px; }
```

And the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JAtLA/

I had to put some of the styles inline with the HTML because the animation wouldn't work any other way. At first I thought the problem  had solely lain in the if conditional of the hideLayer function. But after tweaking it I'm not so sure now.

Comment: mainbutton is invisible in the demo, because it is white against a white background.  also, you are passing in 'mainmenu' to showLayer and hideLayer, but neither method seems to use it.

Comment: Do you want me to change the color for the main button?

Comment: I made this fiddle that more clear : http://jsfiddle.net/7egr7/ and i am trying to find why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "hideLayer" will stop if (layerPosition <= 315).  Is that really what you want?  It happens after 1 iteration.

Note that the y axis goes down the screen (i.e. zero is at the top).

Clicking the button will call showLayer, and then hideLayer.
If the menu is open (i.e. layerPosition > 315), showLayer will not do anything (i guess that is what you intend), and hideLayer will make the menu go up by 5 (from 315 to 320).
On the next iteration of hideLayer (layerPosition <= 315) will be false, so it will not do anything.

Try this:

```
var open = false;

function showLayer() {
    if (open)
        return;

    var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
    var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.top);
    if (layerPosition > 315) {
        hiddenLayer.style.top = (layerPosition - 5) + "px";
        setTimeout("showLayer()", 20);
    }
    else {
        open = true;
    }
}

function hideLayer() {
    if (!open)
        return;

    var hiddenLayer = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
    var layerPosition = parseInt(hiddenLayer.style.top);
    if (layerPosition <= 685) {
        hiddenLayer.style.top = (layerPosition + 5) + "px";
        setTimeout("hideLayer()", 20);
    }
    else {
        open = false;
    }
}
```

In the html, I would like to check if the thing is open or closed before doing anything.

```
<div id="mainbutton" onclick="if (!open) { showLayer('mainmenu'); } else { hideLayer('mainmenu'); }">
```

but `layerPosition <= 685` is the only change that really matters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's what you want but here is my answer :

There is a problem of logic in your code. You wrote

`if(layerPosition<=315){
    hiddenLayer.style.top = (layerPosition + 5) + "px";}`

It means that if the top is 315 or less, the top will increase until it arrives to 316. But in the first function, you say it to stop at 315. So the function hideLayer will just get it moving from 1 pixel.

The solution is to tell him `<400` instead of `<=315` (or something higher than 400).

Here is a modified fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7egr7/2/

Comment: That's odd. It's working now, but when I tried changing the numbers before it didn't. But it works so thank you. You've helped me a lot with my JavaScript. Do you want me to give you some credit when I have my site published?

Comment: it's okay. if you have other questions tell me.

Comment: Well, what I meant to say is that it needs to work over more than one iteration and his code was changed to reflect that. Nothing wrong with your code.